# iOS accessing characters inside a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string

I have a really long string, and I would like to look up some words and characters.
Is there a function in Objective C that is equivalent to c#?

`string string name; string[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called `characterAtIndex:`

```
NSString s = @"hello";
char c = [s characterAtIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit better if you want to look for both characters and words. The characterAtIndex is intended to use only for single char only and makes you add an iteration through the string and check each one for what you're looking for.

```
NSRange range = [@"test12" rangeOfString:@"t12"];
NSLog(@"Position %d: Length %d", range.location, range.length);
```